# cocoa save CIImage as bmp file image corrupted

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-image

On OSX 10.9.5 i'm trying to save an image grabbed with QTkit as BMP file, but the image file output is sliced (corrupted) only if i save as bmp file, like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjXp.jpg

But if i save the image as TIFF or PNG file all is ok here an example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhi09.jpg

The code that i use is

> **-UPDATE-** The image is corrupted only if i apply CIfilter on CIImage *I

```
CIImage *I;

I=[Video cropImg:I];
//saving to disk
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithCIImage:I];
NSImage *nsImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rep.size];
[nsImage addRepresentation:rep];

NSData *imageData = [nsImage TIFFRepresentation];

imageData = [rep representationUsingType:NSBMPFileType properties:NULL];

if ([imageData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:NO]==NO)

{
    NSLog(@"Error file");
}
```

If i change **NSBMPFileType** to **NSPNGFileType** the image is ok, but i need bmp file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should skip the conversion to "NSImage" because the code below works for me.

```
I=[Video cropImg:I];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithCIImage:I];
NSData *imageData = [rep representationUsingType:NSBMPFileType properties:NULL];
[imageData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
```

Comment: No, not work, on my mac the image is sliced, can you tell me if you've compiled 32 or 64? The model of your mac and your version of xcode?